# Golang follow orginal http method

Tags: api, go, postman, http-redirect, go-http

I am trying to call an API so the thing is when I am trying to call it from Postman with "Follow original HTTP method" on it's working fine but on disabling it giving a 400-Bad request response.
[image]

The same thing I am trying to do in my Go code with http client but not able to get success response.
Have tried with CheckRedirect no luck there.

```
httpClient := http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "url", bytes.NewBuffer(data))
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

req.Header.Set("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```

What I can do here to get the success response on redirect? TIA

Answer (score 0):

To not follow any redirects you could use something like:

```golang
httpClient := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    },
}
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "url", bytes.NewBuffer(data))
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

req.Header.Set("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```

Comment: I want to follow the redirects

Comment: Ups sorry, then you should have to do nothing special at all. Maybe check your go version cos there was a problem with redirects before go 1.6 => https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12705